# Type Hint For NamedTuple Returned By Pandas DataFrame itertuples()

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

[ITERTUPLES](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) is a nice way to iterate over a pandas DF and it returns a namedtuple.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4, 2], 'num_wings': [0, 2]},index=['dog', 'hawk'])
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(type(row))
    print(row)
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>
Pandas(Index='dog', num_legs=4, num_wings=0)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>
Pandas(Index='hawk', num_legs=2, num_wings=2)
```

What is a correct way if any to add type hints to the returned namedtuples ?

Comment: I had a similar question where I just needed to get mypy to understand that the `Pandas` object reliably has an `Index` attribute. I have still not found a way to do this, but instead type individual atts like `_index: int = row[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

One posible solution, in case the column names and data types are fixed, is to declare explicitly the data structure of the df row as a NamedTuple:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import pandas as pd


class Row(NamedTuple):
    num_legs: int
    num_wings: int


data = {"num_legs": [4, 2], "num_wings": [0, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=["dog", "hawk"])
row: Row
for row in df.itertuples(name="Row"):
    print(row.num_legs)
```

Comment: This is not type checking and does not answer the original question
https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#function-annotations

Comment: How does it not answer the original question?

It certainly specifies a type int for row ("Row"), wich is valid, and linters / IDEs will check for mistakes there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible, because your dataframe can have any arbitrary data type, and thus the tuples will have any arbitrary data type present in the dataframe. In the same way you can't use Python type hints to specify the column types of a DataFrame, you can't explicitly type those named tuples.

If you need the type information of the columns before going into your for loop, you can certainly use `df.dtypes`, which gives you a Series with the column types.

Comment: Please see my comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74857886/10474024

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4, 2], 'num_wings': [0, 2]},index=['dog', 'hawk'])
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(type(row))
    print(row)
```

You'll notice that the type is `pandas.core.frame.Pandas` -- but this gives an error type checking. You'll need to type check for `pd.core.frame.pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def test_chk(row2chk: pd.core.frame.pandas):
    print(row2chk)
    print(row2chk.num_legs)  # prints the value in the num_legs column

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [4, 2], 'num_wings': [0, 2]},index=['dog', 'hawk'])
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(type(row))
    test_chk(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a slightly modified version of the [Bravhek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73051884/1032586), but with type checking:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple
import pandas as pd
from typing import get_type_hints

Row = NamedTuple(
    "Animal",
    [("Index", str), ("num_legs", int), ("num_wings", int)],
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"num_legs": [4, 2, 'a'], "num_wings": [0, 2, 3]}, index=["dog", "hawk", "bad_record"]
)

# Just a protocol type hint:
row: Row
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.num_legs)


# Actual type checking:
if set(Row._fields) != set(df.columns.tolist()) | {'Index'}:
    print('columns mismatch')
for row in df.itertuples():
    for fn in Row._fields:
        if not isinstance(getattr(row,fn), get_type_hints(Row)[fn]):
            print('type mismatch in column "{}", row "{}"'.format(fn, row))
    print(row.num_legs)
```

It prints the following:

```
4
2
a
4
2
type mismatch in column "num_legs", row "Pandas(Index='bad_record', num_legs='a', num_wings=3)"
a
```

The `protocol type hint` part could be useful to silence IDE warnings (e.g. PyCharm "unresolved attribute reference"), but it would not validate anything.

Comment: Except the question didn't ask for type checking?

Comment: "Type checking" and "type hints" are two tightly connected subjects. An really good and "correct" way to do either of them must be easily extensible to do both. Sadly, in this case, there seem to be no "correct", simple and clean way to do both. Bravhek's answer is not 100% "correct" because `pandas.core.frame.Pandas` is not 100% same as `NamedTuple` and naïve type checking would fail, which made me doubt that this a good and "correct" way at all. With a fairly short and readable type checking code added, Bravhek's code looks a bit more "correct" and "fair tradeoff".